Proof (by induction) that $n \choose i$ is natural for all values of $n$, where $0\leq i\leq n$
Having proven that $n \choose 0$ and $n \choose n$ are both equal to $1$ and thus the statement is true for $n=1$, and then assuming that the statement is true for some value $n$, I wish to prove that ${n+1} \choose i$ is natural.
I referenced a fact that I have already proven, that ${n+1} \choose i$ is equal to the sum of $n \choose i$ and $n \choose {i-1}$. However, per my assumption I can only state that $n \choose i$ is natural (for this $n$), and to prove that ${n+1} \choose i$ is natural (as the sum of two natural numbers, it seems I need to demonstrate that $n \choose {i-1}$ is natural as well).
How would one demonstrate that this is the case?
I looked through the answer in my book and it seemed to follow similar reasoning, but also appeared to take for granted that one can assume the sum is natural and did not elaborate further.

Welcome to MSE. Please try to use this to help you write math formulas https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
